# HTML5 video aspect ratio is wrong when initially loading

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, html5-video

**Update 1**: this is the associated HTML and CSS in the Android cordova app. I didn't add it initially because simply loading the video in the browser with chrome's default video styling still causes the issue, so I didn't think my CSS would be responsible.

```
<div class="pswp">
  <div class="video-centering-container shown">
    <div class="videoHolder">
      <p class="video_container">
        <video width="1088" height="1920" poster="<poster-url>" controls="" loop="" playsinline="">
          <source src="<video-url>" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.pswp {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
    z-index: 1500;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

.pswp * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pswp .video-centering-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.pswp .video-centering-container.shown {
    height: 100vh;
}

.pswp .videoHolder {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.video_container {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 20vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.videoHolder .video_container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
}

.video_container video {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.videoHolder .video_container video {
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

I'm seeing a brief period when an HTML5 video's dimensions are incorrect when the video is initially played. Look at these screenshots:

- after pressing play, before the video loads

[image: before-video-loads]

- after video has loaded and starts playing

[image: after-load-and-is-playing]

I got these screenshots from Chrome on my laptop, but the same problem is happening on an Android [Cordova app](https://cordova.apache.org/). I already set both the `width` and `height` attributes on the video but it doesn't prevent this from happening. I'm serving the video from my own backend. I tried uploading the video to dropbox and serving it from there and the bug doesn't happen. I can see that dropbox adds `preload="auto"` to the `<video>` tag, so I did that too but it didn't help. I'm not sure what else to try, I'm open to any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add your HTML and any relevant CSS to your question? Thanks.

Comment: @AHaworth I've added the HTML and CSS, please have a look. Thanks.